# How to set the multiple default value in laravel livewire

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

i have a multiple product when i get the default value of that product, but when i get that value in input field the default value doesn't show ?

```
<x-filament::page>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <div>
            @if (session()->has('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('message') }}
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <select wire:model="user_type">
            <option value="">Select User Type.....</option>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="distributor">Distributor</option>
            <option value="retailer">Retailer</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <input wire:model="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br><br>
        <input wire:model="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br><br>
        <input wire:model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>

        <div align = "center">Products</div>

       ** @foreach($product as $val)
            <br><br> {{ $val->name }} :
            <input type="number" wire:model="default_price" value = "{{$val->default_price}}">
        @endforeach<br><br>**
        <button type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</x-filament::page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these screencasts. They are very helpful! https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/data-binding

`<input type="number" wire:model="default_price" value = "{{$val->default_price}}">`

Livewire doesn't use `value` attribute!

If you want to update `Product->default_price`, you can use https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-models or if you want to only output the `default_price`, then remove `wire:model`.

Also @foreach(`$products` as $val) `$products` should be plural,
and `$val` should be `$product`, because it is a product variable. Naming is important, if you don't want to confuse yourself and others constantly.